# First-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve this problem:
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=v_0 e^{-t/\tau}-(2/\tau)y\\
\\
y(0)=y_0\\
\end{cases}$$

The solution is:

$$y(t)=v_0 \tau e^{-t/\tau}+(y_0-v_0\tau)e^{-2t/\tau} $$

but I get

$$y(t)=-v_0 \tau e^{-t/\tau}+(y_0)e^{-2t/\tau} $$ which is fasle if we take the derivative...
But i do not understand why!

Thanks you.

My way:

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=v_0 e^{-t/\tau}-(2/\tau)y$

$\dfrac{dy_1}{dt}=-(2/\tau)y$

$y_1(t)=Cte*e^{-2t/\tau}$

$y_1(t)=y_0*e^{-2t/\tau}$

$\dfrac{dy_2}{dt}=v_0 e^{-t/\tau}$

$y_2(t)=-v_0\tau e^{-t/\tau}$

$y=y_1+y_2$

$y(t)=-v_0 \tau e^{-t/\tau}+y_0*e^{-2t/\tau}$

Comment: If you want us to help us find out where you went wrong you better explain how you arrived at your solution.

Comment: I just integrated the two part separatly.

Comment: Could you clarify the steps ?

Comment: I edited the first post.

Comment: Ok, I got the solution ! First solve by using y homogeneous y_h=Cexp(-2t/tau)) and y particular by searching y_p=A exp(-t/tau) to find A=v0*tau then apply y(0)=y0 at the entire solution y=yh+yp to find C!

Comment: Look at your solution at $t=0$, it should be $y_0$. See solution below. Regards

Comment: @Supertoto: Did the answer resolve your issue? Regards

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=v_0 e^{-t/\tau}-(2/\tau)y\\
\\
y(0)=y_0\\
\end{cases}$$

This DEQ can be solved using three different methods (maybe more) using Exact Equations, Laplace Transforms or Integrating Factor (IF).

We start off be rewriting it as:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} + (2/\tau)y = v_0 e^{-t/\tau}, ~~y(0) = y_0$$

We find an IF as:

$$u(t) = e^{\int (2/\tau)~dt} = e^{(2/\tau)~t}$$

Apply the IF to both sides of the DEQ and arrive at the integration:

$$\int \dfrac{d}{dt} ~e^{(2/\tau)~t}~ y(t)~dt = \int v_0 e^{-t/\tau}~dt $$

After evaluating these integrals and simplifying, we arrive at:

$$y(t) = e^{-2t/\tau} \left(v_0 ~ \tau ~ e^{t/\tau} + c \right)$$

Now, we solve for the constant using the IC and have:

$$y(0) = y_0 = v_0 \tau + c \rightarrow c = y_0 - v_0 ~ \tau$$

The final result is:

$$y(t) = e^{-2t/\tau} \left(v_0 ~ \tau ~ e^{t/\tau} + y_0 - v_0 ~ \tau \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your supportive job. Happy Xmas Amzoti. :)

Comment: You are very welcome and Merry XMAS to you my friend! :-)